# text.config not defined in python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def __fontSans(self):     

        global text

        text.config(font=("Comic Sans MS", 8))
```

when i call it in my tkinter program, i get this message

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/megacode/Editor/CodePad.py", line 136, in __fontSans
    text.config(font=("Comic Sans MS", 8))
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that "name 'text' is not defined" *might mean exactly what it says*?  There's certainly no definition of `text` anywhere in the fragment of code you posted; if you actually do have a definition somewhere, it has apparently not been executed yet at the point this function was called.

Comment: well, i do have 

`text=Text(__root)   
    text.grid()`

Comment: @Miketendo08 The logical conclusion then is that `text` is not created in the global scope. Try a `text = None` at the start of the program and a `global text` in each function that uses it.

Comment: @Miketendo08 check like jasonharper suggest if you try to configure text before it is created.